# SparkJava Variables Scope

Tags: spark-java

I'm developing a SparkJava (not Apache Spark) app, and I'd like to share an object between a before filter and a post route. The filter and the route are defined in different classes. I'm not willing to go on with sessions, cause it's a mobile app json api and theoretically speaking, it should be session free. The variable scope should be from the beginning of the request handling until the end.

```
    before(Main.API_PROTECTED + "/*", (req, res) -> {
        String token = req.headers("Authorization");
        if (token == null | "".equals(token)) {
            halt(401, "You're not welcome.");
        } else {
            Partner partner = new PartnerDAO().getPartnerByToken(token.replace("Bearer ", ""));
            if (partner == null) {
                halt(401, "You're not welcome.");
            }
        }
    });
```

There's the above before filter, from which I'd like to share the partner object with the post route below:

```
        post(Main.API_PROTECTED + "/vendors",
            (req, res) -> {
                // Do stuff to insert Vendors in the Database, verifying access control using the partner object
                return "";
            });
```

Maybe in the future, the app will need to scale, so keep in mind that there may be more than one node running this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the object to the request in the filter.

```
 request.attribute("myObject", "my value");
```

Look it up in the post

```
request.attribute("myObject");  // "my value"
```