# Add header to a request

Tags: java, authentication, jwt, spark-java

I'm using nimbus's jwt library to verify a JWT on spark's before function and then I want to pass the JWT's payload only to the next route through the request's headers. However it seems that you can add a key to headers but not a value. I tried:

```
request.headers().add(key)
```

But it doesn't help. What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add a header to your response you should call the header method on your [response](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#response) object, which is the second parameter of the lambda inside your [route declaration](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#routes). You could do so like this: `response.header("FOO", "bar");`

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware that you can add headers to the response but I need to add it to the request since I want to add information on the before() function.

Comment: Maybe you can sove your problem by sharing a variable between the before filter and the route, without the need of adding a header to the request. It that's possible, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33207913/2960660) will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, using attributes will do it.