# Modify Request in Sparkweb framework using RequestWrappers

Tags: spark-java

In my app I want to add a filter using spark.Spark.before for validation, if the request is granted, then I want to add some information to the request itself, so in my spark.Route implementation can access to this information.

But I don't know how to do this

For example:

```
// RequestFilter
before((request, response) -> {
    if (isGrantedRequest()) {
        // modify request adding params, etc
        // maybe using some kind of RequestWrapper
    }
})

.....

post("/", this::handle);

.....

// Request handler
Object handle(Request request, Response response) throws Exception {
    // access to information added in request
}
```

Comment: What information do you want to add to the request? What's your use case?

Comment: For example add some params calculated from an access_token that comes in the request, so if the request comes from an external computer, I puts info for that client using his access_token, for example its user_id, otherwise request from internal network assume a params with user_id is always sent

Comment: You can use session for that.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069768/sparkjava-variables-scope/33207913#33207913).

You can use attributes. Unlike sessions, this wont make your application state full. Further attributes are local to a request and unlike sessions they will have unique value for each request even incase of simultaneous requests.

Set the attribute in the before filter.

```
before((req, res) -> {
    req.attribute("key", "value");
});
```

And read it in the handler.

```
post((req, res) -> {
    String value = req.attribute("key");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *session* for this purpose. It's a place on the request used to set data like you wanted.

In the `before` code you'll create a session and set some attributes in it, according to the result of `isGrantedRequest()` method:

```
Spark.before("/somePath", (req, res) -> {
    Session ses = req.session(true);
    if (isGrantedRequest()) {
        ses.attribute("attr1", "valA");
        ses.attribute("attr2", "valB");
    } else {
        ses.attribute("attr1", "valX");
        ses.attribute("attr2", "valY");
    }
});
```

In the `get`/`post` code you'll retrieve the session attributes:

```
Spark.get("/somePath", (req, res) -> {
    Session ses = req.session();
    if (ses != null) {
        String val1 = ses.attribute("attr1");
        String val2 = ses.attribute("attr2");
        System.out.println(val1 + " " + val2);
    }
    return "";
});
```

Look at [Spark's sessions API](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#sessions) to see more options.

Comment: This solution works, but I think is a workaround and not elegant, I want to use stateless requests and only use filters to intercept like javax.servlet.Filter.doFilter. This way, the code only use information from request without creating a session, but seems I can't, maybe is a limitation of the framework :(

Comment: @AndrésMargalef The only thing that you can modify in the filters is the response (i.e. setting the header/body, changing the type, redirect it). But I'm not sure if that fits your needs.

Comment: I use a workaround with an internal thread local with the info necessary for the request, is not elegant but I don't modify the response. Thanks anyway